# What is the devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize() method used for? And how does it differ from the devise_parameter_sanitizer.for() method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, sanitize

I can't find the use of devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize() method. Please help me it understand its use, and also how it differs from the devise_parameter_sanitizer.for() method.

Answer (score 2):

The `devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize()` method, defined in [the `Devise::ParameterSanitizer` class](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/v4.7.3/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L110), is used by devise in order to filter the allowed parameters, from its controllers, for a given action.

It is very similar to the Rails [strong parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) feature.

You can use it in order to allow more fields than the default one defined by the devise gem.

As of writing, the default action -> attributes are the following has described in [the gem documentation](https://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/ParameterSanitizer#DEFAULT_PERMITTED_ATTRIBUTES-constant):

```rb
DEFAULT_PERMITTED_ATTRIBUTES = {
  sign_in: [:password, :remember_me],
  sign_up: [:password, :password_confirmation],
  account_update: [:password, :password_confirmation, :current_password]
}
```

Basically, as [shown in the gem's documentation `permit` usage examples](https://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/ParameterSanitizer#label-Examples) you pass the `:action` for which you would like to change the allowed attributes, and then call `permit()` on it with the field list:

```rb
# Adding new parameters to be permitted in the `sign_up` action.
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:subscribe_newsletter])

# Removing the `password` parameter from the `account_update` action.
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, except: [:password])

# Using the block form to completely override how we permit the
# parameters for the `sign_up` action.
devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up) do |user|
  user.permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Have also a look at the gem's `README.md` which [explains pretty well all of this](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise#strong-parameters).